# I felt 'disgust' versus 'I felt disgusted'

Tags: past-participles

Have you ever felt disgust at 'being more sociable' or 'having right connections' beating the merit?
I wrote the above sentence but the Grammarly is showing this sentence to be wrong. It asks to change 'disgust' to 'disgusted'. According to it , the correct sentence would be ,"Have you ever felt disgusted..."?
In my opinion, "Have you ever felt disgust?" is alright. Since I am using disgust as a noun it seems alright to me. Why to change it to past participle form? To me, both are alright! What is your say?

Comment: "I feel disgust" is completely normal.  You can ask such basic questions on the terrific English Learner's site

Comment: English prefers verbs to nouns, in speech, especially.

Answer (score 1):

I felt "disgust" is referring to the emotion itself, not your feelings.
I felt disgusted is referring to your emotions about a subject. Example:
I felt disgusted that litter was in the hiking trail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever felt disgust is stilted and awkward. It is technically accurate so feel free to use it, but be aware that it’s not ideal for most purposes.

Also, what is your opinion, or what are your thoughts, are more natural phrases in spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

“Do you feel [noun]?” asks if the person is *capable* of that feeling.

“Do you feel [adjective]?” asks if the person is *currently* having that feeling.

In the past tense, the difference isn’t quite as strong, but there’s still a shadow of it there.